# ROS2 bag record from several topics using node

Tags: ros2, rosbag2

I would like to record ros2 bag using node(python) and that should subscribe to several topics of different message types, can i snippet of code how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried doing a web search like `rosbag2 tutorial site:ros.org` ? There are existing tutorials for both ros1 and ros2.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it. That is for recording single topic. When i try to do the same for multiple topics. I am getting timestamp difference.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't describe the problem, and why you think something is not correct. Please edit your post to provide details.

Comment: I was trying as below to record bag from multiple topics
`
        self.writer.create_topic(left_img_topic_info)
        self.writer.create_topic(right_img_topic_info)
        
        self.left_img_sub = self.create_subscription(Image, '/camera1/left/image_raw', self.left_img_callback, 10)
        self.right_img_sub = self.create_subscription(Image, '/camera2/right/image_raw', self.right_img_callback, 10)
`
I want to record each topic at once, but they are recording unevenly like 2 from first topic and later second topic.
Message filters isn't working to synchronize msgs.

Comment: As I requested, please **EDIT YOUR QUESTION** with these new details. As a test, what happens if you don't use the message filter?

Comment: I tried with message_filters, but in ROS2 those aren't working even if single message stuck in recieving.